# How to resize embedded images in email

Tags: c#, html, css, email

I have the following piece of code which is working fine,
I am being able to send the email with the attachment.

I am trying to resize the image to width of `100px;`

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
Attachment inlineLogo = new Attachment(@"C:\Desktop\Image.jpg");
msg.Attachments.Add(inlineLogo);
string contentID = "Image";
inlineLogo.ContentId = contentID;

//To make the image display as inline and not as attachment

inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
inlineLogo.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;

//To embed image in email

msg.Body = "<htm><body> <img src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\"> </body></html>";
```

**EDIT:**
I tried `<img width="100" src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\">` however it is not working,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
msg.Body = "<htm><body> <img width='100px' src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\"> </body></html>";
```

Or W3C compliant:

```
msg.Body = "<htm><body> <img style='width: 100px' src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\"> </body></html>";
```